# Convertir Lista a Matriz (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

Estoy intentando convertir una lista a una matriz (lista de listas) a partir de una función que recibe un Int (i) que es un contador que siempre inicia en 0, otro Int (n) que es la longitud de cada fila y la lista que tengo que convertir a matriz.

```
crearLdL :: (Int, Int, [Int]) -> [[Int]]
crearLdL (i, n, ([])) = []
crearLdL (i, n, (x:y)) = if (i < n) then [x] : crearLdL (i+1, n, (y))
                                else  [] ++ crearLdL (0, n, (x:y))
```

Esto me da como salida:

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18]]
```

cuando debería ser algo cómo:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18]]
```

en caso de que n sea 6

Alguien tiene idea en que puedo estar fallando? probé varias cosas y no encontré solución.

Gracias

Comment: no e usado haskell pero una logica simple seria
tmp=[]
array=[]
for i in range(18) 
if i%5 ==0 and i != 0:
tmp.push(i)
array.push(tmp)
tmp = []
else
tmp.push(i)
..... con esto le deciamos que creara un arreglo tmp de 5 valores al llegar al 6 entra en el condicional agrega el 6 valor y los pushea a array reinicia el array tmp para otros 5 nuevos valores, el resultado seria algo como lo que deseas!

Comment: Creo que te estás complicando demasiado. En haskell es extraño usar contadores así, y menos pasarlos como argumento en una función recursiva. Tampoco se pasan los argumentos como tuplas, por lo general se pasan *"currificados"*. Lo que no llego a entender es si necesitas esta función así, con esta *signatura*, por algo o tan sólo buscas un modo sencillo de pasar una lista a matriz (lista de listas). De todos modos, has puesto el resultado esperado, pero te falta indicar cuáles son los argumentos que has usado.

Answer (score 1):

Como te dijeron arriba me parece que te estás complicando demasiado intentando hacer una cosa sin pensarlo en 'modo Haskell'. Por lo general, estos problemas que resolverías con un ciclo en un lenguaje imperativo, en Haskell te basta con recursión, sin tener que recurrir (perdón la recurrencia) a contadores como tu variable `i`.

```
crearLdL :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
crearLdL n [] = []
crearLdL n xs = (take n xs): (crearLdL n (drop n xs))
```

Este código resuelve tu problema. `take n xs` devuelve una lista de los primeros `n` elementos de `xs`, y a eso lo pegás a la llamada recursiva `crearLdL n (drop n xs)` donde `drop n xs` es la lista `xs` pero sin los primeros `n` elementos, que son los que ya incluiste antes con el `take n xs`.